# Inner workflow of xcode4 building

Tags: ios, xcode4, build-process

I am developing one application for iPad, this application used some content such as video/audio/image etc, about 8 GB.

So when click the BUILD button in xcode4, it will take nearly 1 hour to build it.

I need to figure out which cause so long time.

I know that once we trigger the building, we have procedures like complier, link etc.(normal sense ), now my purpose is to optimize the building, so need figure out how many procedures happened when trigger building in xcode4, and what is the longest part in my case.

Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Off topic: I don't think that an App with 8 GB video/audio/images is an App that should be on iPad...

Comment: we have our test purpose without publishing to app store. sure, app store will not accept that so large app :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go in `Preferences>Behaviors>Build starts>Navigate to>current log`.